# What csv format is for json array, and how to convert them into json array, Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv

Good day, I been searching for a few hours and couldn't find the result that I want. First of all, I do not know how does a CSV looks like with the following JSON array.

```
[
  { email: "test@test.com",
    contactNo: "123456",
    meta: [
         {key: "Name", value: "Kevin XYZ", type: "string"},
         {key: "Position", value: "Chairman", type: "string"}]
  }
]
```

What's the csv format for the following json array, and how to convert them from csv to json array in NodeJS.

Answer (score 1):

think of your CSV file just like an Excel sheet, where you only have Columns and Rows, so with your preferred structure, you need to define at least these columns:

|| email || contactNo || name || position ||

Those 4 are the most basic header columns your CSV needs, then you'll need a `transformer` function to handle the data structure you want.

In my experience, I'm using `https://www.papaparse.com/` for the CSV Parser, you can have a look at the sample and try it yourself.

In your case, the parser function would be like this:

```js
const parsed = await Papa.parse(csvString, {
  header: true,
  trimHeaders: true,
  skipEmptyLines: 'greedy',
  transformHeader: val => isString(val) ? trimAll(val) : val,
  transform: (val, headerName) => {
    return isString(val) ? trimAll(val) : val
  }
});

//
[
  {
    "email": "user1@user.com",
    "contactNo": "1234-5678",
    "name": "Doe",
    "position": "doctor",
  },
  {
    "email": "user2@user.com",
    "contactNo": "1234-5678",
    "name": "John",
    "position": "developer"
  },
  ...
]
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found out that `npm csvtojson` is much easier to use compare with `npm papaparse`. Please do check out the answer that I post.

Answer (score 1):

This is the csv format to your JSON structure.you can use this [Online converter](https://json-csv.com/) to see how your csv look like.

[image: csv]

This is how you can convert the csv to JSON. You can refer [this good](http://techslides.com/convert-csv-to-json-in-javascript) tutorial to learn how to convert the csv to JSON format. 
The function which is used there is below.

```
function csvJSON(csv){

    var lines=csv.split("\n");

    var result = [];

    var headers=lines[0].split(",");

    for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

        var obj = {};
        var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

        for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
            obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
        }

        result.push(obj);

    }


    return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the function that you gave me when I run on NodeJS, the result are messy. `[{"\"email\"":"\"test@test.com\"","\"contactNo\"":"\"123456\"",...}]`

Comment: That's because it's giving the value as a JSON string. You can add JSON.parse(result) to avoid the "\".

Answer (score 0):

You can use json2csv npm module http://www.mircozeiss.com/json2csv/

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using `npm csvtojson` is much easier.

CSV:

```
email, contactNo, meta.0.key, meta.0.value, meta.0.type, meta.1.key, meta.1.value, meta.1.type
test@test.com, 12345, Name, Kevin XYZ, string, Position, Chairman, string
test1@test.com, 321433, Name, John ABC, string, Position, Accountant, string
```

by using the following code:

```
const csv = require('csvtojson');

const csvStr = "The csv above"

csv()
  .fromString(csvStr)
  .subscribe((jsonObj) => {
    console.log(jsonObj);
  });
```

The result of the json will be:

```
{ email: 'test@test.com',
  contactNo: '12345',
  meta:
   [ { key: 'Name', value: 'Kevin XYZ', type: 'string' },
     { key: 'Position', value: 'Chairman', type: 'string' } ] }
{ email: 'test1@test.com',
  contactNo: '321433',
  meta:
   [ { key: 'Name', value: 'John ABC', type: 'string' },
     { key: 'Position', value: 'Accountant', type: 'string' } ] }
```

In conclusion, using the header `xx.0.yy` is not so user friendly, I recommend just using what `Duc Hong` said.. `header: email, contactNo, Name, Position` and transform to the format that you want.

Comment: thanks for reminding, we as developers might have no issues working this kind of format like `meta_name_first`, but most of the times the CSV file is provided by a client with not much technical background so human error is something we cannot avoid, so usually I stick to the simple choices